# Using Measure value for visual filter

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables . One is the location table with location code. Second table is the customer table that has location code as well. Unfortunately I can connect them as it messes up the other relations for a report that is creating correct results.
I have created a measure that gives me selected location code.

```
Selected Location = SELECTEDVALUE(Location[Duns])
```

All I want to do is add a visual level filter on the customer table slicer based on the value of `Selected Location`.
All the solution I am getting they are assigning the value I just want to do is use the selected value  via measure.
How do I do it?

Comment: create a calculated column in `Customer table` using the measure and use it in the visual filter

Comment: Can you give us some base data and expected result so we can help you better?